# How to use custom function in Model to format Data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

## What I Want to do

I want to convert URLs to tags like this:

```
あいうえおかきくけこhttp://localhostさしすせそたちつてと
```

↓

```
あいうえおかきくけこ<a href="http://localhost">http://localhost</a>さしすせそたちつてと
```

I want to use a custom Function in Model to do it.

## What I did

I added this to my model:

```
class hogehoge extend Model {

    public function convertUrlToLink($value)
    {
        // URLをaタグで囲む
        $pattern = '/((?:https?|ftp):\/\/[-_.!~*\'()a-zA-Z0-9;\/?:@&=+$,%#]+)/';
        $replace = '<a href="$1">$1</a>';
        $text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $value);
        return $text;
    }
}
```

and called it like this:

```
Hogehoge::first(1)->text->convertUrlToLink()
```

But this gives an error:

```
Call to a member function convertUrlToLink() on string (View: /app/resources/views/club/show.blade.php)
```

How can I make custom Function in Model and use it in my templates?

Comment: What is `$value` ? Is it an attribute related to `Hogehoge` ? (Also careful with the case on **h**ogehoge, **H**ogehoge)

Comment: Hogehoge::first(1)->text = あいうえおかきくけこhttp://localhostさしすせそたちつてと

and I wanna modify it like this to use convertUrlToLink method.

```
あいうえおかきくけこ<a href="http://localhost">http://localhost</a>さしすせそたちつてと
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your attribute `text` directly in the model

```php
class Hogehoge extend Model {

    public function convertUrlToLink()
    {
        // URLをaタグで囲む
        $pattern = '/((?:https?|ftp):\/\/[-_.!~*\'()a-zA-Z0-9;\/?:@&=+$,%#]+)/';
        $replace = '<a href="$1">$1</a>';
        $text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $this->text);
        return $text;
    }
}
```

Then you don't need it there

```php
Hogehoge::first(1)->convertUrlToLink()
```

---

If it needs to be reusable, I would do a `static` method (that's only a preference)

```php
public static function convertUrlToLink($value)
{
    // URLをaタグで囲む
    $pattern = '/((?:https?|ftp):\/\/[-_.!~*\'()a-zA-Z0-9;\/?:@&=+$,%#]+)/';
    $replace = '<a href="$1">$1</a>';
    $text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $value);
    return $text;
}
```

Then you use it like this

```php
Hogehoge::convertUrlToLink(Hogehoge::first(1)->text)
Hogehoge::convertUrlToLink(Hogehoge::first(1)->someAnotherText)
```

Comment: What if you have some properties that I want to format in a similar way besides text?